# AngularJS counting radio buttons and undefined value after passing in param

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I spent hours trying to figure out how to count radiobuttons. also I encounter another problem which when I pass value to ng-change that particular value becomes "undefined". so my question is how would I go about passing that value.Also if anyone could help me with the radio button couting that would be awesome.

I only want to count radio button which value is not 0.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="/app/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name={{item.name}} ng-change="updateTotal(item)" ng-model="item.value">
                    {{item.name}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr>
        <p>
            Total checked: {{totalSelected}}
        </p>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

js file:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.data = $scope.createData();
        $scope.totalSelected = 0;
    }

    $scope.createData = function () {
        return [{
                'name': 'cow',
                'selected': false,
                'value': 1
            },
            {
                'name': 'cow',
                'selected': false,
                'value': 2
            },
            {
                'name': 'cow',
                'selected': false,
                'value': 0
            },

            {
                'name': 'rat',
                'selected1': false,
                'value': 1
            },
            {
                'name': 'rat',
                'selected': false,
                'value': 2
            },
            {
                'name': 'rat',
                'selected': false,
                'value': 0
            },

            {
                'name': 'cat',
                'selected': "false",
                'value': 1
            },
            {
                'name': 'cat',
                'selected': "false",
                'value': "2"
            },
            {
                'name': 'cat',
                'selected': "false",
                'value': "0"
            }
        ];
    }

    $scope.updateTotal = function (item) {
        console.log(item);
        if (item) {
            $scope.totalSelected++;
        } else {
            $scope.totalSelected--;
        }
    }
    $scope.init();
});
```

console log:

```
{name: "cat", selected: "false", value: undefined, $$hashKey: "object:10"}
{name: "cat", selected: "false", value: undefined, $$hashKey: "object:11"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `value="{{item.value}}"` to assign a value to `radio` button like following snapshot:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<form ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name={{item.name}} ng-change="updateTotal(item)" ng-model="item.value" value="{{item.value}}">
                    {{item.name}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr>
        <p>
            Total checked: {{totalSelected}}
        </p>
    </form>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.data = $scope.createData();
        $scope.totalSelected = 0;
    }

    $scope.createData = function () {
        return [{
                'name': 'cow',
                'selected': false,
                'value': 1
            },
            {
                'name': 'cow',
                'selected': false,
                'value': 2
            },
            {
                'name': 'cow',
                'selected': false,
                'value': 0
            },

            {
                'name': 'rat',
                'selected1': false,
                'value': 1
            },
            {
                'name': 'rat',
                'selected': false,
                'value': 2
            },
            {
                'name': 'rat',
                'selected': false,
                'value': 0
            },

            {
                'name': 'cat',
                'selected': "false",
                'value': 1
            },
            {
                'name': 'cat',
                'selected': "false",
                'value': "2"
            },
            {
                'name': 'cat',
                'selected': "false",
                'value': "0"
            }
        ];
    }

    $scope.updateTotal = function (item) {
        console.log(item);
        if (item) {
            $scope.totalSelected++;
        } else {
            $scope.totalSelected--;
        }
    }
    $scope.init();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with ng-click to invoke function and use ng-checked for selected property. :)